# Локализовать Яндекс карты на iOS

Tags: objective-c, xcode, yandex-maps-api, локализация, yandexmapkit

Всем привет. Использую YandexMapKit. Платформа iOS. Приложение нативное. Object-C Xcode. Устанавливал через pod 'YandexMapKit', '1.0.7'. Каким образом можно сделать локализацию карт на английский язык?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте метод [YRTI18nManagerFactory setLocaleWithLanguage](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/archive/doc/mapkit/3.0/concepts/ios/runtime/ref/YRTI18nManagerFactory.html#method_detail__method_setLocaleWithLanguage_country_localeUpdateDelegate__nonnullNSString_pointer__nonnullNSString_pointer__nullableYRTLocaleUpdateDelegate)